# Pull Master from featured branch

Tags: git

Probably, this is a newbie question. There's a little confusion about git. What's happened if I pull origin master from my featured branch.

For example:

1. Check out development branch, so I will be on development branch
2. Usually, I just pull from origin development branch
3. What's happened if I run pull origin master from development branch? Does it updated my local master or my local development branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't update your development branch.

Branches are tracked by git, updates will happen on corresponding branch.

Something to read [Git-Branching-Remote-Branches](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)

Answer (score 1):

A git pull without any options will fetch ALL your remote branches, but only merge your checked out branch, because a merge can only happen to a branch that is checked out.

A git pull on a specific branch will only fetch it's corresponding remote branch and afterwards merge this branch to your checked out local branch.